# Power outage during RAID1 build

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I was 60% complete building a two-disk RAID1 on my Ubuntu 14.04 server with the command

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 
/dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

when I accidentally tripped a circuit breaker in my house and shut off the server. Damn. Now when I try to re-run the command I get

```
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
mdadm: failed container membership check
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
```

when I try to check progress I get

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5]
[raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      2929555264 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=PENDING

unused devices: <none>
```

How do I get things going again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building is done (it's immediate). It's the resync that continues now, the difference is that during resync the array is already usable. All seems to be fine here, try writing to */dev/md127* (ie. create a filesystem), and *auto-read-onl*y status should switch to *read-write*. Until the sync is finished the performance will be far lower than normal.

The component devices (*/dev/sd?*) are busy due to being used by the array.

Comment: Oh good, though why is it list as md127 when I "cat /proc/mdstat" when I specified it to be md0?